# Postgres Count records inserted/ updated

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to keey track of a clients database with which we sync.  I need to record `records_added` (INSERTs) and `records_updated` (UPDATEs) to our table.

I'm using an `UPSERT` to handle the sync, and a trigger to update a table keeping track of insert/updates.

The issue is counting records that have are updated.  I have 40+ columns to check, do I have to put all these in my check logic?  Is there a more elegant way?

Section of code in question:

```
select
    case
        when old.uuid = new.uuid
        and (
            old.another_field != new.another_field,
            old.and_another_field != new.and_another_field,
            -- many more columns here                         << This is particularly painful
            ) then 1
        else 0
    end into update_count;
```

Reproducible example:

```
-- create tables
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (uuid serial primary key, another_field int, and_another_field int);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracker_table (
    records_added integer DEFAULT 0,
    records_updated integer DEFAULT 0,
    created_at date unique
);

-- create function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_records_inserted () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$ 

DECLARE update_count INT;
DECLARE insert_count INT;

BEGIN
-- ---------------- START OF BLOCK IN QUESTION -----------------
select
    case
        when old.uuid = new.uuid
        and (
            old.another_field != new.another_field
            -- many more columns here 
            ) then 1
        else 0
    end into update_count;

-- ------------------ END OF BLOCK IN QUESTION ------------------
-- count INSERTs
select
    case
        when old.uuid is null
        and new.uuid is not null then 1
        else 0
    end into insert_count;


-- --log the counts
-- raise notice 'update %', update_count;
-- raise notice 'insert %', insert_count;

-- insert or update count to tracker table
insert into
    tracker_table(
        created_at,
        records_added,
        records_updated
    )
VALUES
    (CURRENT_DATE, insert_count, update_count) ON CONFLICT (created_at) DO
UPDATE
SET
    records_added = tracker_table.records_added + insert_count,
    records_updated = tracker_table.records_updated + update_count;

RETURN NEW;

END;

$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS example_trigger ON example;

CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger
AFTER
INSERT
    OR
UPDATE
    ON example FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_records_inserted ();

-- A query to insert, then update when number of uses > 1
insert into example(whatever) values (2, 3) ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE SET another_field=excluded.another_field+1;
```

Comment: I would use a test on `IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') AND NEW.* ! = OLD.*`. That would catch a change that occurred in any field.

Comment: Not directly related, but you should not use UUID as a column name. Postgres supports a [data type UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-uuid.html). Your create table then builds a column name UUID which is an integer data type that is auto increment from a sequence. It is not that this an error (at least currently) but is at best confusing. I would suggest the column name be just ID, or EXP_ID.